# how to get onclick method to work outside of onCreate()?

Tags: android-studio

I am confused here... let's say that you have a new class and would like to add a clickable image button to that class, can that be done? I read somewhere that it needs to be in the `onCreate` method, which is only found in the `activity_main xml` file though......

I am also having another error, where I can't find the solutions. I am having a zero constructor error in my second class when trying to use the intent method to take the user from the first class to the second class, would appreciate some assistance here as it is taking me too long to find the answers...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    PaintView pv = new PaintView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.practice);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaintView.class));
        }
    });
```

My `PaintView` class is too long, just wondering if you could suggest which part of the code I should correct?

This is the error message:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

I put the `setOnClickListener` under my `MainActivity.java` and also tried it under the `PaintView.java` class but none is working...

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaintView.class)); this code used to start only activity not paint class that you pass

Comment: I understand and I did create an activity but it is still under a java class correct? I am still getting errors but I think my main problem is in my setOnClickListener... I am always getting the null reference error and read some posts here but still can't fix it... I am so confused

Comment: instead of: startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaintView.class)); 
use this code: Toast.makeText(this, "on click listener working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: I have the following errors:

Comment: Toast.makeText(this, "on click listener working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     ^
    method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
    method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaintView.class)); means that you want to move from one activity to another, and here according to you, you want to move to a class??? And where is the button with the "practice" id located? in your case, it should be in the main activity layout, right?

Comment: strange... when I tried adding this code... the message appears:

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"YouTube Button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Is it my manifest file?

Comment: I think the problem is that in order to get the activity to work, I must use AppCompatActivity but in order to do a paint drawing app, I am using view instead... So how can I get this to work?

Comment: I am also trying to get my OnClickListener to work in my second class but from a paint app tutorial that I am working on, does not include the onCreate method. How can we get the onClickListener to work without the onCreate method?